Third-party charging cable not working after update to iOS 17.6.1
I have received an Otterbox charger from my employee with my iPhone 14. I've just updated to iOS 17.6.1 and found out that charging doesn't work anymore. As soon as I plugin an original Apple cable the iPhone charges again. Why is this and can't I use this Otterbox charger? It has a much longer cable which I like to use and is it even allowed to make you devices be limited to charge only by your own cables.

What Otterbox charger do you have (model)?

Test with a third cable. If that works, then that would prove that your first cable is broken. Third-party cables work fine for me. You can be sure the media would be all over it if Apple somehow stopped third-party cables from working.

that would be strange, before the update I could use the cable without problems...I don't have any other 3rd party cable however.

The timing may be purely coincidental. A defective cable is by far the most likely scenario. Can you test the same cable in a different setup? Like straight to a power adaptor.

Turned out, after receiving a new charging cable, it wasn't the cable but the charger itself who's defective. Could have checked that immediately by testing the cable in a different charger.

@Thinkr: the wall charger is an Otterbox OBFTC-007.
